# Can someone identify Desert Rose Leaf problem?

Tags: diseases

I bought this Desert Rose from a big box store on clearance about a month ago. The leaves had this trailing/patchy lighter discoloration on the leaves when I purchased. Thought I could re-pot it and fertilize and get rid of the issues. Although I am seeing new growth, the leaves still look the same. Does anyone know what it is and how I should treat it?

Thank you!!

[image][image][image][image]

Comment: anything going on underneath the leaves, on their backs - insects or something that shouldn't be there?

Comment: Thank you for your reply Bamboo. I had not thought to look there so good question..I tried to look tonight but it was too dark by the time I saw your comment. I will look at the underside of the leaves tomorrow and let you know.

Comment: Good Morning Bamboo. I checked the underside of the leaves and did not find any crawling bugs but did find a patch of some type of eggs. Not sure what kind they are and not sure if they were laid before or after I bought the plant. I took pics but I don't see where I can include it. I'm new to the site.

Comment: Ok I added it to my original post. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I just went and looked again and found the bug/aphid? in the pics above on one of the leaves.

Comment: In the second photo, you clearly see eggs. I don't know what kind of eggs, but you better remove them (with damp cloth or something), before they are from harmful bugs. Also you can see that the upper leaf in the second photo is damaged by [leaf miners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaf_miner). I can't tell you what kind of insects mine through your leaves, but it is not good for your plant, that's for sure.

Comment: Thank you b.nota. I went ahead and removed the whole leaf that the eggs were on. I also dusted the plant with Sevin dust. I hope that will help with the miners you mentioned.